# Set of lower dimension has Lebesgue measure zero?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f(x):\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous strictly monotonic function. For example, $f(x)=\tanh(x)$.

Does the set $\{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n : \sum_i f(x_i) = 0 \}$ have Lebesgue measure zero?

If $f(x)$ is a linear function, then the set is a $n-1$ dimensional linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, [for which the Lebesgue measure is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056707/lebesgue-measure-of-a-subspace-of-lower-dimension-is-0). But what if $f(x)$ is nonlinear?

Comment: What methods do you know to show that a set has Lebesgue measure zero? Have you tried to find an answer for the case $n=1$ or $n=2$?