# Every subset of a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dim $<n$ has measure 0

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have read in my teacher’s book the following statement.

> - Every subset A of a subspace C of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $dim(C)<n$ has measure 0

And I’m having issues proving it and mainly understanding why. Is it because measure space $(\mathbb{R}^n , M( \mathbb{R}^n),  \lambda_n)$ where $M( \mathbb{R}^n)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of the measurable sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\lambda_n$ is Lebesgue Measure is a complete measure space?

Comment: I assume "measure $0$" means "Lebesgue measure $0$". But what kind of dimension do you use? If you look at the definition, the question should answer itself. Anyway, you should include it in the question.

Comment: Actually there are $0$-dimensional subsets of $\mathbb R^1$ with positive Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you recall from calculus, if we integrated over a region, say $\displaystyle\int_{[a,b]}dx$, we would get the area of a rectangle with base length (b-a) if we were in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\displaystyle\int_{[a,b] \times [c,d]}dx$,  the volume of a parallelepiped whose base has length (b-a) and width (d-c).

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, the measure of A is the volume of the set A. If dim C $<$n, then one of the dimensions of the higher dimensional rectangles is 0.

So if the set A is a square, it has volume 0. Thus the square would have measure 0. Now generalize this idea to higher dimensions.