# Question on Probability of Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

Let
$$V = \{ v \in M_{33}| \text{ equal column sums} \}$$
be a vector space.

How would you calculate

$$P( \text{ equal column sums} | v \in M_{33} )$$

?

How would you go about solving these types of problems in general?

Comment: Can you say what P() means? I guess it is a probability but of what and what is the sample space?

Comment: $V$ is the set of matrices with equal column sums and you are wondering about the probability that a matrix has equal column sums, given you know it is a matrix from the set $V$? This is just $100\%$?

Comment: No,  V is the set of matrices with equal column sums but the question is about V as subset or [math]M_{33}[/math].

Comment: You haven't specified a distribution over $M_{33}$, but for any reasonable distribution, the probability that the column sums are all equal is $0$.

Comment: Sample space is all 3 x 3 matrices, I want to know the probability of choosing a matrix such that the column sums are equal. So this probability is equal to zero? Because the set of 3 x 3 matrices has cardinality much greater than the set of 3 x 3 matrices with equal column sums? I suppose the distribution I had in mind is that each element has equal probability.

Comment: @RaoulConstantine: As to the distribution, please see [Why isn't there a uniform probability distribution over the positive real numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14777). As to your question about cardinality: No, it's not a question of cardinality but of measure. The condition that the column sums are equal reduces the dimension, and sets of lower dimension have measure zero in the higher-dimensional space.

Comment: Ok that’s really interesting and has lead to good further reading on measure theory. For example this thread helped https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618340/sub-dimensional-linear-subspaces-of-mathbbrn-have-measure-zero

Can you recommend any other further reading or threads? Thanks