# I proved any linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to prove $\overline{T}$ has measure zero. (Munkres "Analysis on Manifolds")

Tags: measure-theory, linear-transformations, volume

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

> Theorem 20.1. Let $A$ be an $n$ by $n$ matrix. Let $h:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be the linear transformation $h(x)=A\cdot x$. Let $S$ be a rectifiable set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $T=h(S)$. Then $$v(T)=|\det A|\cdot v(S).$$

> Proof.
> $\cdots$
> Consider now the case where $A$ is singular; then $\det A=0$. We show that $v(T)=0$. Since $S$ is bounded, so is $T$. The transformation $h$ carries $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto a linear subspace $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension $p$ less than $n$, which has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^n$, as you can check. Then $\overline{T}$ is closed and bounded and has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
> $\cdots$

I wondered why $\overline{T}$ has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
I proved this as follows:

> Proposition 1.
> Let $V$ be a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
> Then, $V$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

> Proof.
> If $V=\mathbb{R}^n$, then $V$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
> If $V\neq\mathbb{R}^n$, then we can write $V=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: B\cdot x=0\}$ for some $p$ by $n$ matrix whose row vectors are linearly independent. Since $x\mapsto B\cdot x$ is continuous, $V_1:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: B\cdot x>0\}$ and $V_2:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: B\cdot x<0\}$ are open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
> Therefore $V=\mathbb{R}^n-\left(V_1\cup V_2\right)$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

> Proposition 2.
> $\overline{T}$ has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

> Proof:
> $h(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose dimension is less than $n$.
> So, by [Sub-dimensional linear subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ have measure zero.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/618340/1226161), $h(\mathbb{R}^n)$ has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
> Since $h(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $h(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$ by the preceding proposition.
> Since $T=h(S)\subset h(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $\overline{T}=\overline{h(S)}\subset h(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
> Since $\overline{T}$ is a subset of $h(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $h(\mathbb{R}^n)$ has measure zero, $\overline{T}$ also has measure zero.

I proved any linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Is this proposition necessary to prove that $\overline{T}$ has measure zero?

***I found a fatal error in my proof of Proposition 1.

But I believe the result is true.***

Comment: It is true that finite-dimensional linear subspaces are closed and your proof looks ok to me. It is true, but perhaps worth realising why such $B$ exists. You can take a basis of $\Bbb R^n$ whose first $p$ entries are a basis of $V$, for instance, and use that in a few different ways to conclude the subspace is closed

Comment: @FShrike thank you very much for your comment.